# Selenium + PhantomJS opens webpage different than regular browser

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs, viewport

I started to write web scraping code in Python recently. I was able to do a lot just using requests and BeautifulSoup. Then when I tried Staples website, I can't find the element that shown in the Developer Tools in Chrome. I did a little research and thought it might be JavaScript. I tried ghost.py and QtWebKit, and they have this SSL issues. Then I tried Selenium + PhantomJS.

```
executable_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '\\phantomjs.exe'
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=executable_path)
browser.get(url)
html = browser.page_source
browser.save_screenshot('./abc.png')
```

The [screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6Wmh.png) is different than the [screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMLDO.png) from Chrome. **In Chrome, there is a price block which is no shown in the PhantomJS browser**. I also tried a customized header, there is no difference.

```
headers = { 'Accept':'*/*',
'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, sdch',
'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.8',
'Cache-Control':'max-age=0',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, 
like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36'}

for key, value in enumerate(headers):
    capability_key = 'phantomjs.page.customHeaders.{}'.format(key)
    webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS[capability_key] = value
```

I want to scrape the price from the webpage. Is there some setting for Selenium I can use to get the same webpage as a regular browser?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any issue as such in your code block. I have taken your code block and executed the same `Test` capturing the snapshots in **default** and  **maximized** modes and here is the result with the screenshot with the `URL` **`http://www.google.com`**.

---

### PhantomJS (Default [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)) :

When we initiate **`PhantomJS`** in default configuration, as `PhantomJS` is headless (nothing is shown), [**`viewportSize {object}`** property](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/viewport-size.html) effectively simulates the size of the window like in a **traditional browser**. Hence the initial page loaded is **portrait** sized as follows :

- Minimal Code :

  ```
  browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'C:\\Utility\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe')
  browser.get("http://www.google.com")
  html = browser.page_source
  browser.save_screenshot('./Screenshots/PhantomJS_normal.png')
  browser.quit()
  ```
- Snapshot :

[image: PhantomJS_normal]

---

### PhantomJS (Maximized [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)) :

But when we initiate **`PhantomJS`** in default configuration and then simultaneously invoke the **`maximize_window()`** method the [**`viewportSize`**](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/viewport-size.html) effectively simulates the size of the entire screen as follows :
 - Minimal Code :

```
    browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'C:\\Utility\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe')
    browser.get("http://www.google.com")
    browser.maximize_window()
    html = browser.page_source
    browser.save_screenshot('./Screenshots/PhantomJS_maximize.png')
    browser.quit()
```

- Snapshot :

[image: PhantomJS_maximize]

---

### Conclusion

So it is pretty clear from the above two pictures that the default initiation of **`PhantomJS`** browser have a lesser [**`Viewport`**](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/viewport-size.html) while if we invoke **`maximize_window()`** the [**`Viewport`**](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/viewport-size.html) is enlarged. Hence we can interact with more elements. So it is expected that to get majority of the page elements visible within the [**`Viewport`**](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/viewport-size.html) you have to maximize the browser.

Comment: I tried. This is not helping. I actually use **bold font** to emphasize what is different from 2 screenshot. Please read the questions again and try this [url](https://www.staples.com/dell-i5567-7526gry-15-6-laptop-computer-intel-i7-256gb-ssd-8gb-ddr4-win-10-intel-hd-graphics-620/product_2677757)