# Parse a dynamic HTML Page using PhantomJS and Python

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, webdriverwait

I would like to scrape an HTML page where content is not static but loaded with javascript.

I downgrade Selenium to version `3.3.0` in order to be able to support PhantomJS (`v4.9.x` does not support PhantomJS anymore) and wrote this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('path-to-phantomJS')
driver.get('my_url')
p_element = driver.find_element_by_id(id_='my-id')
print(p_element)
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: "errorMessage":"Unable to find element with id 'my-id'"
```

The element I want to return is tag `<section>` with a certain `id` and all its subtags. The HTML content is like that:

```
<section id="my-id" class="my-class">...</section>
```

Comment: You need to wait for the JS to load the element. See [Waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/)

Comment: After the page loads what steps do you take manually for see the element with the id you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: "errorMessage":"Unable to find element with id 'my-id'
```

...implies that the element wasn't found within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).

The possible reason is that the desired [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70203974/7429447) didn't [render](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47237075/7429447) within the [Viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130869/7429447) as [phantomjs](/questions/tagged/phantomjs) by default initializes with a ***minimized*** viewport.

---

### Solution

You need to initialize [PhantomJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70437976/7429447) with the [***maximized viewport***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48164705/7429447) inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) while locating it as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('path-to-phantomJS')
driver.get('my_url')
driver.maximize_window()
p_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "my-id")))
print(p_element)
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to various reasons, such as the element not being present at the time the code is executed or the element having a different ID, but in case you double-checked the ID presence. I think you have to make sure that the page has finished loading before attempting to find the element. In certain cases, JS-based content may take a bit longer to load. You can add delays or an explicit **wait** to ensure that the element is available before accessing it

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('path-to-phantomJS')
driver.get('my_url')
delay = 10  # Wait up to 10 seconds for the element to be present

try:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, delay)
    p_element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'my-id')))
    print(p_element.text)
except TimeoutException:
    print("Timeout!")
```

Hope this helps!